How to know whether a wallet has an airdrop?
How to know whether an address has receive an airdrop of token ?
Example - https://etherscan.io/tx/0x47b185d59cba6c8ec070576df5d2bd7493b365130bc823fd836473eed7d604ff
In this transaction, multiple addresses has recieve the same amount of token. Does it mean all have address have received the airdrop ?

You are talking about how to detect it? Or how to look for address in that transaction?

@CT95 I want to know how to detect it !

It's pretty hard to say about "Airdrop". But you can simple track an ERC20 transfer event of an address. In your example tx, you can see more than 1000 logs, it means every address receive token will raise a log. You can scan or listen event Transfer on an address to view it.
